# I can't partition my hard disk in disk utility

Tags: windows, disk-utility, imac, partition

After I deleted Windows from my Intel iMac (OS X 10.6.8) using The Boot Camp Assistant, I tried to install Windows 7 again, but when I reach the part of partitioning, the iMac got stuck and stopped working.

I can't partition my hard disk using the Disk Utility app, either. I try to factory reset my iMac, but I am still facing the same problem. Currently, the internal HDD can't be mounted. Any help please....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you clarify? If this an iMac or a PC? Or something else? Can you provide the output from the command `diskutil list`?

Comment: I should also point out that taking Windows 7 from a clean installation to a version with the latest available updates is difficult to do. Windows update probably will not work unless you first manually install some necessary updates.

Comment: hello david i wannna thank you first the problem is the internal hdd can't be mount . this is imac with mac os x 10.6.8 intel bass

Comment: Are you saying the Mac will not boot to OS X? Do you have the original OS X installation DVD?